# How to display image uploaded in frontend edit form?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I added attribute "my_image" to customer, and I uploaded the images, but I can't display it in frontend edit form. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 30 minutes try, I found the answer for my question. All I need is just add this code in template:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'myimage'. DS .$login->getData("my_image");?>" alt=""/>
```

At first I was missing . DS .